# Excel formula to convert "Today, 10:18:03 AM" or "Tuesday, May 14, 2013 12:06:36 PM" to Excel date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Can someone come up with a formula to convert strings like the following to Excel dates? Note that it will say "Today, *time*" if the date matches today's date, otherwise it will say the day name. You can assume that the string I am trying to convert is in column A, if that helps.

- `Today, 10:18:03 AM`
- `Tuesday, May 14, 2013 12:06:36 PM`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should work:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,5)="Today",TODAY(),DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1))))+RIGHT(A1,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Excel is in spanish so you'll need to translate the functions.

```
=SI(IZQUIERDA(A1;5)="Today";HOY();SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Jan";0;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Feb";31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Mar";31+28;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Apr";31+28+31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="May";31+28+31+30;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Jun";31+28+31+30+31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Jul";31+28+31+30+31+30;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Aug";31+28+31+30+31+30+31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Sep";31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Oct";31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Nov";31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31;SI(IZQUIERDA((DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)));3)="Dec";31+28+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30;"ERROR"))))))))))))+IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(A1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)-4);2))+VALOR(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(A1;11);8))+SI(DERECHA(A1;2)="PM";0,5;0)-SI(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(A1;11);2)="12";0,5;0)+FECHA(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(A1;16);4);1;1)-1
```